# Meaning and Usage of the word 'Welter'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Could anyone make this understand to me the meaning and usage of the word 'Welter'?

I gone through Vocabulary.com and found this.

> Use the noun welter to describe an enormous, messy pile, like the
>   jumble of papers, coffee mugs, pens, and food wrappers on the desk of
>   the messiest person in the office

How can I use this word as a noun and as a verb in making a correct sentences?

Could anyone let me know the more simple and understandable meaning with proper example?

**What is the meaning of welter of emotional argument?**

Comment: You ask several different questions, but to respond to the one in bold; per your quoted definition, a "welter" is a "a big mess". Thus, a "welter of emotional argument" is a "mess of emotional argumentation". This might be contrasted, for example, with a clean and rational argument (in other words, "rational" is the opposite of "emotional" in the context of argumentation, as "clean" is the opposite of "messy").

Comment: +1 just for _welter_ I haven't heard that word, in that sense, used in decades. Where did you hear or read it?

Comment: @Frank: Went through an Article in 'The Hindu',which was all about the judicial independence.

Comment: This link provides the meaning both as a verb and as noun with example sentences: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/welter

Comment: I found the article here http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/lead/lead-article-a-red-herring-for-judicial-independence/article6391843.ece _welter_ is in the first paragraph. I think it's being used in the sense of mental _confusion_ as Dan Bron suggests in his comment, rather than physical _mess_.

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries on line gives the noun meaning as 'a large number of items in no order; a confused mass' such as *a welter of conflicting rules*. Also 'a state of general disorder: *the attack petered out in a welter of bloody, confused fighting*.

Answer (score 1):

Oxford Dictionaries on line gives the noun meaning as 'a large number of items in no order; a confused mass' such as *a welter of conflicting rules*.

Also 'a state of general disorder: *the attack petered out in a welter of bloody, confused fighting*.

There is a verb meaning as well.

The term 'welterweight' used in boxing as a grade between light and middleweight is of unknown origin.

Answer (score 0):

I have only come across the word in the context of the phrase 'a welter of blows' which would link in with its usage in 'welterweight' and would refer to a flurry of punches in a fight or boxing match.